# Javascript filter function with sorting not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, filter

I have one json in below format

```
const myData = [{
  "A111" : "123"
  "name" : "abc",
},
  "A222" : "678"
  "name" : "xyz",
},
{
  "A333" : "456"
  "name" : "abc",
},
{
  "A444" : "643"
  "name" : "abc",
},
{
  "A555" : "078"
  "name" : "xyz",
}]
```

```
const test = {
  "123" : "6789",
  "456" : "999",
  "078" : "1234"
}
```

Now I want all data from myData whose name is "abc", and data should be sorted on basis of second object values. I think based on second objects keys we can do.But I am not getting it. Output should be in array of objects which will contain name from first json and values from second object in sorted manner depending on secong object values sorting will be done.  . Can someone please help . Thanks in advance. Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me know if this is something what you need.

```js
myData = [{ "A111" : "123","name" : "abc", }, {"A222" : "678", "name" : "xyz" }, { "A333" : "456", "name" : "abc", }, { "A444" : "643", "name" : "abc", }, { "A555" : "078", "name" : "xyz", }];

var test = { "123" : "6789", "456" : "999", "643" : "1234"}

var result = myData.filter(val=>val.name=='abc').sort((a,b)=>Object.keys(a)[0] - Object.keys(b)[0]);

// Or in case if you need to sort on the basis of test object

var result2 = myData.filter(val=>val.name=='abc').sort((a,b)=>test[Object.values(a)[0]] - test[Object.values(b)[0]]);

console.log(result);
console.log(result2)
```

Comment: I did this  
var result = myData.filter(val=>val.name=='abc').sort((a,b)=>Object.keys(a)[0] - Object.keys(b)[0]);

// Or in case if you need to sort on the basis of test object

var result2 = myData.filter(val=>val.name=='abc').sort((a,b)=>test[Object.values(a)[0]] - test[Object.values(b)[0]]);

console.log(result);
console.log(result2); But getting empty array as response.